# TSP in warehouse (multiple localization of one item)

Tags: c#, optimization, traveling-salesman, warehouse

I wanna write my masters thesis about computer optimization of warehouse processes because I work as a programmer in a shipping company and I thought it might be useful.

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to adjust a TSP problem to create a path to picking items in warehouse, with the assumption that one product can be in more than one localization (1 main loc but 1-2 additional)? In my company, most of the products are in one place but my major advisor told me that it would be too trivial.

How should I start (I'm familiar with classical TSP problem)? I tried search similar issues but I didn't find anything useful. Maybe somebody has some ideas or know resources about that?

Also, it is possible to use some ready-made solution in C# (like dlls) with an implementation of algorithms and adjust it to my problem? Somebody knows some libraries that I could use?

Picker has 20-150 products to pick so I thought about using brute force (for small data sets), greedy and genetic algorithms to optimize this process.

Comment: First, I'm fairly certain this is off topic for SO.  Try programmers or mathematics.  Second, I had to solve this exact issue for the exact problem you describe.  Cost is a function of both nodes.  You can select the nearest location of the second item, and ignore any farther item.  The requirement for vanilla TSP is that all costs must be non-negative.  I agree with your advisor.  On the other hand, determining what items to put where is much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Generalized Traveling Salesman Problem (GTSP): The nodes are grouped into clusters, and we have to find the shortest cycle that visits exactly one node from each cluster. In your case, the clusters would be the products and the nodes would be the individual instances/locations of the products.

Don't know of any off-the-shelf code for it, but a google search will net you lots of heuristics you can code.

Comment: Why exactly one node? It shouldn't be whole path in each cluster? Could you be more specyfic?

Comment: Imagine an order has 5 items called A, B, C, D, E. Each of those items could be located in several different parts of the warehouse. A "cluster" consists of all items of one type, e.g., all the A items. So you want to find the shortest path that visits one node from each cluster -- one A, one B, etc.